# How can I SCP file from Linux host to Windows host with Git Bash?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, scp

I installed `git for windows` on a Windows 7 host. The Git for Windows comes with a program called `git bash`. I can use `scp` to transfer files to a Linux host in a git bash Window, as follows:

```
 MINGW64 ~
 $ scp  from-windows-file  linuxuser@LINUX-HOST-IP:/home/linuxuser/
```

But when I transfer files back to a Git Bash window from a Linux host, scp not work, as follows:

```
 $ scp  from-linux-file   winuser@WINDOWS-HOST-IP:/c/Users/winuser/
```

I got an error:

```
ssh: connect to host WINDOWS-HOST-IP port 22: Connection refused
lost connection
```

How can I transfer files *back* to a Git Bash window from a Linux host?

Answer (score 1):

You should remain in mingw64-shell and do:

```
$ scp linuxuser@LINUX-HOST-IP:/home/linuxuser/from-linux-file .
```

It will copy the file to the current directory keeping the filename.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for `ssh: connect to host WINDOWS-HOST-IP port 22: Connection refused` is because your Windows doesn't have an SSH server running. So the solution is to keep an SSH server running as a service to listen to SSH connections. [Windows 10 has a built-in OpenSSH server](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/openssh-in-windows-10/) so no need to install a server anymore

Alternatively you can copy from Linux, just swap the source and destination